# Бесконечный цикл for в python

Tags: python, циклы, for, while

Хочу создать бесконечный цикл for в python, не хочу использовать while нужен именно for

Можно ли это реализовать?

Интересуют из любопытство или так сказать научного интереса)

Comment: Вы хотите есть суп лопатой и копать землю вилкой. While - это цикл итерационный. for - цикл с параметром. Применяйте, пожалуйста, циклы по назначению

Comment: @АлексейБелкин у вас ни кто не спрашивал советов как правильно "---жить---" программировать. Написано же интересует из любопытства, чтобы понять как устроен язык

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Есть довольно известный рецепт для этого:

```
for _ in iter(int, 1):
    pass
```

В `iter` передаётся *функция* и *заградительное значение*, при достижении которого функцией итерации заканчиваются. `int()` при вызове без параметров выдаёт `0`, заградительное значение выставлено `1`, этот цикл никогда не закончится.

Comment: В общем случае не обязательно число, а вообще любое значение, на котором итерация заканчивается. [В примере из документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) - пустая байтовая строка при чтении из бинарного файла: `for block in iter(partial(f.read, 64), b''):`

Comment: @insolor Ну да, тут корректнее написать "значение", конечно, да

Answer (score 8):

еще можно воспользоваться бесконечными итераторами из модуля `itertools`: `count()`, `repeat()`, `cycle()`:

```
from itertools import repeat

for _ in repeat(0):
    pass
```

Comment: Можно и так, да, но это уже с использованием библиотек :)  Хотя такого ограничения у автора вопроса не было вроде, да

Comment: @CrazyElf, у данного ответа есть одно преимущество - этот кусок кода гораздо легче понять человеку, который не писал этот код )

Comment: @MaxU это да, выглядит понятно :)