# Каким образом можно создать бесконечный цикл используя "FOR"

Tags: python, консоль

Необходимо создать бесконый цикл используя только FOR, именно бесконечный, а не огромным количеством в range().

Comment: Дубликат <https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1357645/%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB-for-%D0%B2-python>

Comment: Думаю, перед тем как задать вопрос, стоит хотя бы погуглить.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1357645/Бесконечный-цикл-for-в-python

Comment: @СергейКох, какой дубликат? Здесь же без конины...))